# Online resources for learning statistics, exercises (with solutions)?

Tags: probability, references, inference, descriptive-statistics, teaching

I'm currently working as a teaching assistant at my university, in an introductory statistics course (for medical students).

Offline, there are many books available with information to aid the teacher.  However, what I am interested to know is if you might direct me to any (good) **resources that provide exercises (with solutions) in statistics, which are available online?** (e.g: teachers notes).

The subject material can range between descriptive statistics, probability, and parametric/non-parametric statistical inference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a totally amazing online resource for multi-level modelling, not sure if that's any good to you:

http://www.cmm.bristol.ac.uk/

Even includes a test at the start to give you an idea of where to start.

And should this be community wiki?

Comment: Thanks Chris.  This should be a wiki - but I don't have permissions to make it so :)

Comment: I'd vouch for those materials as well. They also have intro tutorials and not just multi level modelling resources.

Answer (score 1):

It might worth checking Udacity Statistics course https://www.udacity.com/course/st095
or Berkeley Introduction to Statistics: Descriptive Statistics https://www.edx.org/courses/BerkeleyX/Stat2.1x/2013_Spring